# How to have different JSON responses registered for a GET call

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
GET http://localhost/foo/api/v1/bars/:id
```

How to have different JSON responses registered for a GET call. We would like the GET call to return a separate response based on whether a CLI is invoking or the user interface is calling the API by passing a query parameter. But how do we register different serializers dynamically on the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [User-Agent request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) to identify the application doing the request. There are good tutorials to check how to access the headers in Spring, like this [Baeldung one](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers).